# Running multi-statement query using JDBC on DB2 windows

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to run multi-statement queries using JDBC on DB2 10.1 Windows but it fails with a syntax error. Following is the query-

```
SELECT * FROM schemaname.tablename;
```

> Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "schemaname.tablename".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.13.127

I understand that this comes due to the semi-colon at the end of the query which is not understand by the database. How can I set the query separator as semicolon so get through this.

Comment: What is this "multistatement query" that you are talking about? May be you could show some of your code that causes the error?

Comment: It is basically of the form SELECT * FROM schemaname.tablename1;SELECT * FROM schemaname.tablename2;  Two queries separated by a semicolon. However, my requirement isn't  exactly that. I need to run a query that ends with semicolon as they are coded that way and run fine with DB2 for z/OS, I need to run the same with DB2 for Windows. I don't have the option to alter the queries.

Comment: Neither of these is possible. You can only issue one statement at a time, unless using a [compound statement](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053781.html), and it should not have any terminators (because terminators are _not_ part of the SQL syntax).

Answer (score 0):

With JDBC you execute one statement at a time; by the looks of it DB2 doesn't support it. Some drivers/databases have a way around this, but it is non-standard.

So instead of trying to execute two statements in one go, you will need to execute them one after the other.

Comment: Strange enough that it works on DB2 for z/OS but I haven't found much info for the Windows version.

Comment: @User2709 As far as I know, there is not one 'DB2', there are multiple variants that are all called DB2, and features and support vary between platform and variants.